# Attach Rel Attribute to Element from 3rd Parent JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-1628 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
<dl class='gallery-item'>
    <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href='2829970281_large.jpg'><img width="300" height="300" src="2829970281_large-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="2829970281_large" /></a>
    </dt>
</dl>
<dl class='gallery-item'>
    <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href='2829970282_large.jpg'><img width="300" height="300" src="2829970282_large-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="2829970282_large" /></a>
    </dt>
</dl>
<dl class='gallery-item'>
    <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <a href='jpeg.jpg'><img width="300" height="300" src="jpeg-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="jpeg" /></a>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

How can I select the parent `div`'s gallery `id` and add a `rel` attribute to the children `<a>` tags with JQuery?

This is what I have so far which is not working:

```
$('.gallery-item a').attr('rel', $(this).parent('div').attr('id'));
```

The desired effect would be that each `<a>` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="" rel="gallery-1">
```

and I intend on using this for multiple galleries, all with different ID's on the page, but the 3-4 `<a>` tags within them should be given the `rel` attribute of their parent div container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't refer to the selected elements, you can use the `.attr()` callback function. Within the context of the callback which is executed once for each element, `this` refers to the selected elements. Also `parent` only selects the *parent* element, you should use `.closest()` instead:

```
$('.gallery-item a').attr('rel', function() {
    return $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Yep.  Perfect.  I'm puzzled as to why `this` doesn't refer to the current selected element, but this worked perfectly.  Thanks!  Will mark answered in 8 mins.

Comment: @RCNeil You are welcome, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) might help.